# Is "I cannot best you" valid sentence?

Tags: meaning, verbs, sentence

In video game "Skyrim" enemy warriors some times cry

> I cannot best you!

and run away.

Is "I cannot best you" valid sentence?

Does it mean: "I cannot defeat you"?

Can I ask question: "Can you best me?"

Comment: To best: (tr) to gain the advantage over or defeat.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Best** is a valid verb. It's usage in the given sentence is also valid.
From the [google definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20best&es_th=1)

> *verb, informal* outwit or get the better of (someone).